# How to scroll down to the end on Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram, infinite-scroll

I tried to scrape the urls of posts from instagram based on a hashtag "foody".
Using selenium and beautifulsoup, I could scrape around 2,160 urls of posts.

However, I could not scrape beyond that (there are more than 4,000,000 posts). Are there any alternatives to scrape the entire posts with "foody" hashtag? Or at least urls of posts that were posted between 2018-2019?

Below is my code for **scraping**.

Thanks!

```
    
    
    instagram_url = "https://www.instagram.com" 
    tag_url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags"
    ads = "foody" # hashtag
    
    #pausetime
    pause_time = 2
    
    #driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
    
    #go to hashtag page
    driver.get(f"{tag_url}/{ads}")
    time.sleep(pause_time)

    #scroll down
    lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    match=False
    i = 0
    while(match==False):
        #urls
        html = driver.page_source
        bs_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        for roots in bs_html.find_all(name="div", attrs={"class":"Nnq7C weEfm"}):
            for link in roots.select("a"):
                real = link.attrs["href"]
                if real not in reallink:
                    reallink.append(real)
        print("appendend data: ", len(reallink))
        
        #Scroll down   
        lastCount = lenOfPage
        print(f"scrolling down {i}")
        i += 1
        time.sleep(pause_time)
        lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        if lastCount==lenOfPage:
            match=True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **Social Scroll for Instagram** extension (I know it's really basic but it works). As **Alvaro Bataller** said if you write some script to scroll down then after scrolling several post instagram system will atomically block you for certain period of time thinking you could be a bot.

But this extension has a built in cool down system and it will pause the scrolling so that insta system won't mistake you as a bot. And it could easily reach you to the end post without getting time blocked by insta.

Comment: btw google chrome perhaps removed this extension from the webstore, but you could find the archival version on the internet of course... website like crx4chrome

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript I was able to scroll down for 3176 images, going back 2 years and 4 months.

I found a total of 3166 images. After that it says "fail to load".

I tried repeated this experiment again and it seems it wouldnt let me scroll down much now.

My guess is that Instagram has some sort of limit of how much you can scrape so people don't abuse their servers.